# Configuring Http Proxy for all Docker Containers

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have 5 containers but I want to give different HTTP proxy for all containers

For example, my DB container port is `8989`

I added to path `~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
   "proxies":{
      "default":{
         "httpProxy":"http://127.0.0.1:8989",

      }
   }
}
```

Should I do for each container and how can I test this worked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not done at the Docker configuration level, instead with port maps

### Docker Run

Using Docker Run command you must do it via the flag `-p` or `--publish`:

```
docker run --publish 127.0.0.1:8989:8989 db
```

So this will map the port `127.0.0.1:8989` on the host machine to the container `0.0.0.0:8989`, therefore you need to ensure your container is listening on `0.0.0.0`, and not on `127.0.0.1`.

### Docker Compose

In docker compose you can use `ports` inside a service to define the ports maps:

```
services:
  db1:
    image: database-image-name
    ports:
      # Database reachable from the internet
      - "8901:8989/tcp"

      # Database only reachable via localhost
      - "127.0.0.1:9901:8989/tcp"
  db2:
    image: database-image-name
    ports:
      # Database reachable from the internet
      - "8902:8989/tcp"

      # Database only reachable via localhost
      - "127.0.0.1:9902:8989/tcp"
```

> **NOTE**: this is not a full `docker-compose.yml` file example

If you only need to access the database from another container in the same network, then you can remove the `ports` from your docker composer file, and reference the database from the other container by using it's service name, that in this example is `db1` or `db2.

Comment: Thanks a lot .It saved me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Just to inform you, that you can also upvote an answer when you mark it as the accepted one.